# Procedure Too Large in private sub worksheet_selectionchange(byval target as range)

Tags: excel, vba

This macro will execute another macro when the wanted cell is active.

This macro works till column X. Adding more after that produces the "procedure too large" error. I think it has reached its capacity limit. How do I make the code shorter/work?

Note: this code continues till column AA and the only thing that changes are the range columns ("B11"->"C11") and code (B_11 -> C_11).

Picture 1: Columns B:AA is areas and rows 11:14 are tasks.

The code calls different macros set for those cells. Example cell B11 calls for B_11 macro and so on.

Select area&task
[image]

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count = 1 Then

' B-Column Click Macro------------------------------------------------------------

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B11")) Is Nothing Then Call B_11
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B12")) Is Nothing Then Call B_12
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B13")) Is Nothing Then Call B_13
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B14")) Is Nothing Then Call B_14

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B16")) Is Nothing Then Call B_16
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B17")) Is Nothing Then Call B_17

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B19")) Is Nothing Then Call B_19
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B20")) Is Nothing Then Call B_20
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B21")) Is Nothing Then Call B_21
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B22")) Is Nothing Then Call B_22

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B24")) Is Nothing Then Call B_24
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B25")) Is Nothing Then Call B_25
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B26")) Is Nothing Then Call B_26
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B27")) Is Nothing Then Call B_27

' C-Column Click Macro------------------------------------------------------------

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C11")) Is Nothing Then Call C_11
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C12")) Is Nothing Then Call C_12
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C13")) Is Nothing Then Call C_13
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C14")) Is Nothing Then Call C_14

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C16")) Is Nothing Then Call C_16
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C17")) Is Nothing Then Call C_17

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C19")) Is Nothing Then Call C_19
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C20")) Is Nothing Then Call C_20
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C21")) Is Nothing Then Call C_21
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C22")) Is Nothing Then Call C_22

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C24")) Is Nothing Then Call C_24
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C25")) Is Nothing Then Call C_25
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C26")) Is Nothing Then Call C_26
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C27")) Is Nothing Then Call C_27
```

continues till range("AA11")... call AA_11

Picture 2: After clicking for example cell B11 the below macro that is named B_11 will be active. The purpose of this macro is to filter mass data to the wanted area and task. So column B = Area 082M and Row 11 = Frame. In the datasheet, areas are set in rows and tasks are in table headlines so to filter tasks I need to hide unnecessary columns.

After call_11 macro
[image]

```vb
Sub B_11()
'
' Area-082M


    Sheets("Tasks").Select
' hiding unnecessary columns
    Columns("F:BI").Hidden = False
    Columns("J:BI").Hidden = True

' filter data to only area 082M
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2435").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        "082M"
End Sub
```

Comment: What `B_11` to (probably) `AA_27` are? Procedures to be called? If so, should they do something different for each cell, or only use the respective cell value to process it in a similar way?

Comment: @FaneDuru do you want the excel that is in the question, i can send it to you if it helps to understand what i mean.

Comment: https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/procedure-too-large-in-private-sub-worksheet_selectionchange-byval-target-as-range.48778/ @FaneDuru here is the files if needed.

Comment: OK. I will look at it and adapt the code to do what your many macros do, or call those macros.

Comment: Much appreciated, it would help a lot! :) If i can ask, where did you learn to write macros? @FaneDuru

Comment: I learned only by myself, by trying and doing... Now internet is full of examples and even this community can offer you solutions for almost everything.

Comment: admirable to learn all this by yourself! Btw do you have any complex macro works to show? this is still so new for me so I haven't seen all the potential VBA haves! @FaneDuru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. I only supposed that your rest of the sausage code keeps the same  pattern...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'if selection contains more than a cell, the code exists
    
    Set rng = Me.Range("B11:AA14,B16:AA17,B19:AA22,B24:AA27") 'the discontinuous range where the selection to trigger the event
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Dim MacroName As String
        MacroName = Split(Target.Address, "$")(1) & "_" & Target.Row 'build the macro to be called name
     
        Application.Run MacroName 'call existing macros
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code is triggered only if a cell in the necessary range is selected, then it builds the name of the existing sub to be called and calls it (`Application.Run MacroName`)

**Edited**:

The next version will call a single `Sub` (instead of all existing), configured to act according to selected `Target` cell address. I configured it only up to "F" column (`LiteralP` variable). It will send an elocvent message if you try selecting cells situated after F:F column...

The adapted event will look like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'if selection contains more than a cell, the code exists
    
    Set rng = Me.Range("B11:AA14,B16:AA17,B19:AA22,B24:AA27") 'the discontinuous range where the selection to trigger the event
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        doTheJob Target
    End If
End Sub
```

And the called `Sub` like this:

```
Sub doTheJob(Target As Range)
   Dim LiteralP As String, ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject
   Dim rngUnhide As Range, strRng As String, crit As String
   
        LiteralP = Split(Target.Address, "$")(1) 'extract the literal part of the Target address
        
        Set ws = Sheets("Hyttityöt"): Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2435")
        ws.Columns("F:BI").Hidden = False    'common for all cases: unhide the respective columns range
       Select Case LiteralP                               'select specific filter criteria:
            Case "B"
                crit = "082M": If Target.Row = 21 Then strRng = "F:AK,AP:BI"
            Case "C"
                crit = "081M": If Target.Row = 21 Then strRng = "F:AC,AP:BI"
            Case "D"
                crit = "093M": If Target.Row = 21 Then strRng = "F:AK,AP:BI"
            Case "E"
                crit = "092M": If Target.Row = 21 Then strRng = "F:AC, AP:BI"
            Case "F"
                crit = "091M": If Target.Row = 21 Then strRng = "F:AK, AP:BI"
                
            ' complete the necessary Target literal part, up to AA
            Case Else
               MsgBox "Letter " & LiteralP & " has not been configured above...", vbInformation, "Not configured...": Exit Sub
       End Select
       Select Case Target.Row               'select the appropriate ranges to be hidden:
            Case 11: strRng = "J:BI"
            Case 12: strRng = "F:I,N:BI"
            Case 13: strRng = "F:M,R:BI"
            Case 14: strRng = "F:Q,F:BI"
            Case 16: strRng = "F:U,Z:BI"
            Case 17: strRng = "F:Y,AD:BI"
            Case 19: strRng = "F:AC,AH:BI"
            Case 20: strRng = "F:AG,AL:BI"
            'Case 21 looks specific for each letter address...
            Case 22: strRng = "A:O,AL:BI"
            Case 24: strRng = "F:AS,AX:BI"
            Case 25: strRng = "F:AW,BB:BI"
            Case 26: strRng = "F:BA,BF:BI"
            Case 27: strRng = "F:BI,F:BE"
        End Select
        
        ws.Range(strRng).EntireColumn.Hidden = True 'hide the above established columns range
        tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData                                     'show all filter data
        tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=crit      'apply the filter for the fourth field
        If Target.Row = 13 Then tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="SEMI"    'apply the second filter on the third column, different criteria
        If Target.Row = 14 Then tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="HYLSY" 'apply the second filter on the third column, different criteria
        
        ws.Activate
End Sub
```

The code will be more compact, easier to be adapted if needed and using common variables declared and set only once. I think it shouldn't be difficult to continue the `Sub` configuration, looking to what I've done. If something not clear, I will try clarifying it if you ask for clarifications...

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this comment. B_11 to AA_27 are filters code, that filter table data. To give you a better vision of my (noob) work: columns are set as areas -> B = area 82M and rows are set as work tasks ->11 = cleaning. Clicking B_11 cell will take you to another sheet and filters the data to only show area 82M cleaning tasks.  For example B_26 = Area 82M inspection, U_26 = Area 140M inspection. @FaneDuru

Comment: @new_atVBA  Please, download your working workbook, using the above code event, from [here](https://easyupload.io/d0oy71). Your event has been inactivated and the above one works, calling your existing Subs. Anyhow, their code looks primitive, no offence, but it will take to much time to collect all the necessary data to update them all...

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! I have no education about writing macros, so it's understandable that my work seems primitive, so I appreciate the critics. :)  If I can ask a few more questions, how would you start writing this macro with the same functions but an easier way to collect data( if í understood your last sentence right) Can you recommend some videos that are used in your macro? This is optional, you already helped me so much and I can't even thank you enough! May you and your close one have a happy week! :)

Comment: @new_atVBA Now I am not near my laptop, but I will try writing the beginning of a function better dealing with your case... Besides that, I would also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...

Comment: Please, download the updated workbook form [here](https://easyupload.io/i1o4k1). Like I wrote in the edited answer, I updated the called `Sub` only up to F:F column. You should do the rest of the job based on what I did up to that point. It shouldn't be too difficult, I think. If the logic of 21 row range to be hidden configuration follows the pattern up to F:F ( the same from two and two letters) the code can be simplified using at the end another Select `Target.row` which accepts more conditions, separated by comma. I mean `Case "B", "D", "F":  strRng = "F:AK,AP:BI"`...

Comment: Thank you @faneduru for the homework, I will do it later. I have run into another problem, not specifically VBA but VBA saving to OneDrive that others can edit/use my macro live (without downloading the file). I saved the file to OneDrive to shared it with others but when they opened the file, this warning pops up [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tILzm.png). The "solution" i found is this [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-has-blocked-macros-from-running-because/4bf4eb8d-5545-4e00-a6a7-a0801e264cc2). Is there a solution without downloading the file.

Comment: @new_atVBA This is not related to your question at all... In order to avoid the pop-up, your "others" should add the folder to Excel Trusted Locations. Directly, as the path is, or mapping it and add the mapping directory. Check also 'Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended)'. But, related to the question, I told you something about **accepting the answer**. Did you missed it or you did not care about it?

Comment: I'm sorry! I kinda miss understood the message and will do better in the future. Thank you once again! have i now accepted the answer ?@faneduru